# No traces of a user's shopping website until user reopens shop?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a friend that found one more problem with the shopping website, her StackOverflow account (Displayed ID name is Ruth) has been used to ask a question for something else today and could not ask another one until two days later. So I have decided to ask the question for my friend.

She is creating a shopping website that allows users to create an account and open a website. If they choose to close down the shop, there is a button for it. So far on the database table, there is a disabled field for the shop, so that the user can reopen the shop again, so she's not completely deleting the shop from the table. But she wants the users not be able to find the information and items of that closed website. So basically no traces of the website is there until the shop owner opens it back up again.

How to make it so that others are not able to find any traces of the website and its items all at once?

Comment: whatever `select` query your `"Friend"` uses should only select records where the `disabled` field is false

Comment: _“has been used to ask a question for something else today and could not ask another one until two days later”_ - those restrictions are in place for a reason, and not to weasel one’s way around by asking a friend to ask instead. Plus, discussing such stuff via a “man in the middle” is not really helpful IMHO; communicating technical issues to a newbie directly can be a tough enough task already - having an additional person in the mix is only going to water that down further.

Answer (score 0):

It's simple, you add a flag in the database table for example Enabled (boolean) and depending on the condition you fetch the data accordingly.

In your php file, you can fetch the result of the shop from MySQL and if the shop enabled is false, you display a page saying that it's not reachable otherwise you display the shop.

Depends on your application's logic.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the "disabled" field on a user or shop table? I think it would be easier to implement it on a shop table, that way your shop is set to disabled more clearly.

In this case, I do not think having no traces of the shopping website is even accurate to put. Are you fetching data from a get variable to show the items of that shop? Okay, maybe the ID of that item still exists, because you need it to exist if you still have the table and all the shop items not deleted. What you can do is set up an if statement when the page receives the get variable to display that item. This statement tests whether the item's shop is disabled or not, and this you would need MySQL to help. So when it is disabled, just redirect them to a 404 page or an error page of your customization.

Now, when you do go looking for that shop's website, that should also redirect to a page saying that the shop is not existing. Although this practice is not entirely the best (in terms of security), it may very much be what you are looking for.